# Go binary.Read into slice of data gives zero result

Tags: go, encoding, binary

I want to read and write binary data to file and my data is simply slice. The encoding part is working, but my decoding via `binary.Read` gives zero result. What did I do wrong?

```
    data := []int16{1, 2, 3}
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(buf.Bytes())
    // working up to this point

    r := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())
    got := []int16{}
    if err := binary.Read(r, binary.LittleEndian, &got); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Read failed:")
    }
    fmt.Println("got:", got)
```

Running this code gives

```
[1 0 2 0 3 0]
got: []
```

The playground link is here:
https://go.dev/play/p/yZOkwXj8BNv

Comment: `got` las a length of 0, so you read 0 `int16`s (you don't need `r` here, you can read from `buf` without the extra copy, that's what a buffer is for after all)

Comment: Thanks, @JimB, in real case, I write that `buf` to disk, then later read the bytes from disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make your slice as large as you want to read from your buffer. You got an empty result because got has a length of zero.

```
got := make([]int16, buf.Len()/2)
if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &got); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("binary.Read failed:")
}
```

And as JimB stated, you can read directly from your buffer.

See also the documentation of [`binary.Read`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#Read)

> Read reads structured binary data from r into data. Data must be a pointer to a fixed-size value or a slice of fixed-size values. Bytes read from r are decoded using the specified byte order and written to successive fields of the data. [...]

Comment: What if I don't know the data size? In real usage, I write the encoded data to disk, then load it, at that point, the data size is unknown

Comment: You can read the data from the file with `io.ReadAll` into an array. But be sure you have enough memory to hold it. Otherwise, if the file is too large, you can read it in chunks, decoding on-the-fly. Check the source of `io.ReadAll` to get an idea how to implement it.